# Is it ok to have 2 controls in 2 different forms/usercontrols to have the same name?

Tags: .net, vb.net, naming, name-collision

Let's say I have declared a oledDbAdapter1 in Form1, and another in Form2 with exactly the same name. Will this cause any conflict?

Comment: Have you tried it? Was it ok?

Comment: Yes. No problem so far. But I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the **fully qualified** object name must be unique. So in your case you have:

```
MyApplication.Form1.oledDbAdapter1
```

and

```
MyApplication.Form2.oledDbAdapter1
```

Where MyApplication is the name of the Application or Assembly

So this will not cause an issue. But you can't have two objects called `oledDbAdapter1` in `Form1`